# CSS file not fully loading on localhost

Tags: css

I have ran into an CSS error and my problem lies in localhost debugging.
CSS is refusing to fully load and line breaks at certain line.

[image]

Here is the example of unexpected line break,
the file itself is around 170kb.

Rules: 1322
Selectors: 1793

It works fully when hosted, but not locally.
Any clues? (all browsers affected)

Edit:
Its asp.net,
no its not random, if I do delete some parts of it, other "section" loads.
Full css is at: http://test.gohome.it/Content/css/gohome.css?v=aHR0cHM6Ly9wcmltZXJneS9zdm4vR29Ib21lL3RydW5rOjEwODcw
Its loading properly.

Comment: what are you using to serve the files?

Comment: do you generate the css? is there an error? can we reproduce your issue somehow?

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help

Comment: Please share your CSS code and it's declaration/serve function. Does it break at a specific line or is it aways random?

Comment: Added link to full css file that works on server.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is supposed to go on there with the cutting-off issue - but you got **loads** of errors in there anyway, https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.gohome.it%2FContent%2Fcss%2Fgohome.css%3Fv%3DaHR0cHM6Ly9wcmltZXJneS9zdm4vR29Ib21lL3RydW5rOjEwODcw&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: I've seen the errors, but the designers are assuring me its ok.

Comment: What do designers know about coding?

Comment: @04FS Ha! "We assure you all these errors that would effectively stop a style from being applied are OK."